Angular FormGroup Control valueChanges property is not firing pipe for Angular Material Autocomplete filter
somewhat new to Angular. I have a form for my application that allows the user to create a new data entry. Part of the requirements for this project is that some of the fields utilize autocompletion. I've tried subscribing to the valueChanges property on the appropriate controls, but console log statements seem to indicate that these only fire once at construction time. I have tried identifying why the autocompletion is not being filtered dynamically as text is entered into the input but I cannot find it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
create-booking-component.ts
  filteredOriginCities!: Observable<string[]>;
  filteredDestinationCities!: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private bookingService: BookingService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Create form
    this.createBookingForm = this.fb.group({
      bookingId: ['', Validators.required],
      shippingMode: ['', Validators.required],
      origin: ['', Validators.required],
      destination: ['', Validators.required],
      pickupDate: ['', Validators.required],
      deliveryDate: ['', Validators.required],
      tons: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(40.0)]]
    });

    // Subscribe to changes in origin and destination city fields for autocomplete
    this.filteredOriginCities = this.createBookingForm.get('origin')!.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => {
        console.log('Filtering on value: ' + value);
        return this._filterCities(value);
      })
    );
    this.filteredDestinationCities = this.createBookingForm.controls['destination'].valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filterCities(value)),
    );
  }

create-booking-component.html
    <!-- Enter Origin and Destination City Fields -->
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Origin City</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="origin" [matAutocomplete]="originAuto">
        <mat-autocomplete #originAuto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let city of filteredOriginCities | async" [value]="city">
                {{ city }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>

I have tried accessing the FormGroup controls using .controls['origin'], I have tried assigning a separate variable to the individual control, and then subscribing to it's valueChanges via the new variable, etc. I am using Angular 17.

Hi, your code looks fine to me. Demo. Can you reproduce it in StackBlitz? Thanks.

Thanks Yong for the demo! I think what I was missing was the AsyncPipe import, working on my end now. Appreciate the help!

Looking at Yong's demo, it seems that this issue was caused by missing imports  AsyncPipe or ReactiveFormsModule, as I had never passed the [formModule] directive my FormGroup.
